# My mutations works properly with Amplify but not with Apollo. Why?

Tags: graphql, apollo, apollo-client, aws-appsync, aws-amplify

I'm using `AWS AppSync` with `Apollo`. So far, so good except that I just realised that all my mutations are not working properly :

In the devtool, I can see the returned data like this:

```js
{
  "data": {
    "getProduct": {
      "productId": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
      "title": "my title",
      "slug": "my slug"
    }
  }
}
```

...but when I try to console.log these same data, I get null.
It does that only with my mutations (queries works fine).

```js
{
  "data": {
    "getProduct": null
  }
}
```

Here is what I'm doing:

```
addProduct(variables): Observable<Product> {
  return this.apollo.mutate({
    mutation: gql`
      mutation addProduct($product: AddProductInput) {
        addProduct(product: $product) {
          productId
          title
          slug
        }
      }
    `,
    variables
  }).pipe(
    tap(console.log)
  )
}
```

**After few hours trying to find a solution, I tried to replace `Apollo` with `AWS Amplify` and It worked as expected.**

The thing is that I don't want to use `AWS Amplify`. I can't use fragments/offline/optimistic UI/fetchPolicy... and I really need these.

So I'm wondering if that is supposed to be like this or am I missing something here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the help of [Kamil Kisiela](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4035768/kamil-kisiela), we have find out that it worked again when adding `disableOffline: true` to `AWSAppSyncClient`.
So I looked for bugs that looked like this and I found [this](https://github.com/awslabs/aws-mobile-appsync-sdk-js/issues/170).
Then I upgraded  `aws-appsync` to `1.3.3` and it worked all the time, even without `disableOffline: true`. Yay!